# Space Between TextField SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my credit card textfield

```
 struct CreditCardView: View {

@State private var number: String = ""
var body: some View{
    TextField("Card number", text: $number)
        .textFieldStyle(
            RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()
        )
        .padding([.top])
  }
}
```

This is my card number text

```
 struct CreditCardFront: View {
    let number: String
    var body: some View {
                Text(number)
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
   }
```

How can I insert space between every 4 numbers? Now when I fill the textfield with 1234123412341234 I see 1234123412341234.

I want to see those numbers as 1234 1234 1234 1234

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string extension and apply the pattern.

```
extension String {
    func applyPattern(pattern: String = "#### #### #### ####", replacmentCharacter: Character = "#") -> String {
        var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
            guard index < pureNumber.count else { return pureNumber }
            let stringIndex = String.Index(utf16Offset: index, in: self)
            let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
            guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
            pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
        }
        return pureNumber
    }
}
```

usage

```
struct CreditCardFront: View {
    let number: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(number.applyPattern()) //<-- Use here
            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold, design: .default))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but I think the OP wants the spaces added into the input text field as the user types. (I know how to do that with UIKit, but am still new to SwiftUI.)

Comment: @DuncanC after ending char you can directly assign to text field binding var (number) using onReceive or onChange method or custom binding.